# Deleting by Uri with ContentResolver

Tags: android, uri, android-tv, android-contentresolver

I am trying to delete content (chanel's program) like:

`content://android.media.tv/preview_program/317`

with this code:

```
    getContentResolver().delete(TvContractCompat.buildPreviewProgramUri(ALlProgramIDs.get(i)), null, null);
    // ALlProgramIDs.get(i) = 317; long type
```

or this code:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(ALsProgramIDs.get(i)), null, null);
// ALsProgramIDs.get(i) = content://android.media.tv/preview_program/317
```

and nothing to be happen. Programs are not deleting.

**BUT this code:**

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(ALsProgramIDs.get(i).substring(0, ALsProgramIDs.get(i).length() - 3)), null, null);
// LsProgramIDs.get(i).substring(0, ALsProgramIDs.get(i).length() - 3 = content://android.media.tv/preview_program/
```

works fine - everything from this Uri (or storage) is deleted.

**What is wrong with deleting certain IDs?**

Seems done like here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/tvprovider/media/tv/PreviewProgram

*Usage example when deleting a preview program:*

`getContentResolver().delete(TvContractCompat.buildPreviewProgramUri(existingProgram.getId()), null, null);`

Comment: What is `TvContractCompat.buildPreviewProgramUri(ALlProgramIDs.get(i)`?

Comment: this is `ArrayList<Long>` with IDs

Comment: We cannot see that. Is you use an id then hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

```
getContentResolver().delete(TvContractCompat.buildPreviewProgramUri(programId), null, null);
```

Should work, so you may want to connect the debugger and step through it to verify you're passing the ID you want to delete and that the built URI is correct. An alternative that will make your code more readable is to use the PreviewChannelHelper's [deletePreviewProgram](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/tvprovider/media/tv/PreviewChannelHelper#deletePreviewProgram(long)) method.

```
PreviewChannelHelper(context).deletePreviewProgram(id);
```